# Linear functionals on a locally convex TVS

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space and $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional. If there is an open neighborhood $U$ of the origin such that $f(U)\neq \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is continuous.

**My attempt:** there is a basic convex neighborhood $V$ of $0$ contained in $U$. Then $f(V)\neq \mathbb{R}$ and $f(V)$ is convex, hence an interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, it is sufficient to prove that $f(V)$ is bounded. But I did not find a way to prove this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $X$ is supposed to be locally convex, we can suppose that $V$ is convex, balanced and absorbent.

By hypothesis, there exists $y \in \mathbb R \setminus f(V)$.

Suppose that $y > 0$. If $y <0$, consider $-f$ in the arguments below. I claim that $f(V) \subset (-\infty,y)$. If not, there exists $x \in V$ with $f(x) > y$. Then $f(\frac{y}{f(x)}x) = y$. A contradiction as $\frac{y}{f(x)}x \in [0,x] \subset V$ because $V$ is supposed to be convex.

As $V$ is supposed to be balanced, we also have $-x \notin V$ and with a similar proof than above, we can conclude that $f(V) \subset (-y,y)$. In particular, $f(V)$ is bounded.